# mysql and php: setting config variables on start - impact on server?

Tags: php, mysql

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Guayaquil');
$cnn->execute('SET NAMES utf8');
$cnn->execute('SET GLOBAL time_zone = "-5:00"');
```

Hi, the code above is run everytime someone enters the website im developing. Does someone know what the impact (in performance) of those commands is?

Comment: Prefer [`mysql_set_charset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php), **not** `SET NAMES`. This function properly updates the charset to be used by `mysql_real_escape_string`. If you use only `SET NAMES`, an unfortunate combination of default and new character sets can make `mysql_real_escape_string` fail in the same way as `mysql_escape_string` always did, potentially giving you SQL-injection security holes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of the PHP `date_default_timezone_set` command: negligible

Of the two MySQL commands: Unlikely to be significant.

Don't you mean `SET SESSION` rather than `SET GLOBAL`? If you're doing it for just the connection...

Edit: To expand on my answer, I have a script that gets included from just about every PHP script on my site that sets various configurations like date_default_timezone_set, starts sessions, defines functions and so on. It also sets the SQL mode to "TRADITIONAL" with the database connection. I think setting some configuration options is something you shouldn't try to avoid.

Comment: thanks! i actually meant GLOBAL based on what i read. What would be the difference, though?

Comment: As per: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/set-option.html two significant differences are: 1) "The SUPER privilege is required to set global variables." 2) "If you change a session system variable, the value remains in effect until your session ends or until you change the variable to a different value. ... If you change a global system variable, the value is remembered and used for new connections until the server restarts." Based on what your apparent desired behaviour, SET SESSION is what you want.